# Add decimal value to div classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs with the same class. Each div has a number which I need to add a decimal place to. The html is like this:

```
<div class="demo">14214</div>
<div class="demo">23455</div>
<div class="demo">45645</div>
<div class="demo">76554</div>
<div class="demo">77655</div>
```

I need the results returned like this using jQuery:

```
<div class="demo">14.214</div>
<div class="demo">23.455</div>
<div class="demo">45.645</div>
<div class="demo">76.554</div>
<div class="demo">77.655</div>
```

The jQuery code I've been working on is:

```
$.each($('.demo'), function (index, value) { 

var number = parseInt($(this).text());
var addcommas = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number);

var adddots = addcommas.toString().replace(',', '.');

$(this).innerHTML = adddots;

});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o65rchzL/59/)

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, your only mistake is you used the wrong function to try and update the div. Logging the final value of `adddots` to the console demonstrates this when debugging.

`innerHTML` works on DOM elements, not jQuery objects. The jQuery equivalent is `.html()`.

So you can do

```
$(this).html(adddots);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/o65rchzL/62/ for a demo.